# Prevent loosing sudo privileges when I exit out of python virtual enviroment

Tags: centos, sudo, python, python3

I have a Linux VM moderated by my companies IT team which I have sudo access on.  I've discovered that if I enter, then exit, python virtual environment I will lose sudo permission, getting the standard "you aren't in sudoers, This incident will be reported to god, country, and Santa Clause" error message.

Usually if I su to the user I already am running as I get my sudo power back, occasionally I don't.  Closing my terminal entirely and reopening it does not fix my sudo permissions.  I can sudo from within the virtual environment, it's only lost when I leave the environment.

I've checked and I am not anywhere in the sudoers file.  That being said I know my home directory is being mounted from the cloud, so I presume my sudo privileges are likewise coming from some cloud magic.  Presumably some sort of environmental settings are being setup that are wiped by the python virtual environment, but I'm not sure which settings are being lost or how to arrange to keep that setting across virtual python sessions.

So how can I keep my sudo power while navigating around virtual environments?  My teammates answer is to just su to root and stay there, I *REALLY* don't want that to be my answer...

Comment: What does the output of `id` look like before entering the venv, inside the venv, and after exiting the venv? Same for the output of `sudo -l`